# WPF ,conditionally bind item to detail view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code and it's taking me forever to fix can any one help me please

```
                   //contains list of client computers 
                  //I want to show the detail of a user in the 
                   selected  client 

                <ListBox x:Name="clientsListBox"
                         Margin="0,0,772,27"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource clientTemplete}" />

              // i did the following 
             <Grid Name="UserDetailGrid"
                      Width="414"
                      Height="336"
                      Margin="566,13,0,0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem,
                                            ElementName=clientsListBox}"

                      >


                    <Image Margin="156,10,193,262" Source="/EtimerServer;component/rec/user.png" />
                    <Label Width="196"
                           Height="41"
                           Margin="89,84,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Content="{Binding CurrentUser.Name}" />

                    <Label Width="280"
                           Height="54"
                           Margin="56,260,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Content="{Binding CurrentUser.StartSession}" />
                    <Label Width="280"
                           Height="66"
                           Margin="56,161,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Content="{Binding CurrentUser.ElapsedTime}"
                           FontFamily="Open 24 Display St"
                           FontSize="48"
                           FontWeight="Normal" />

                </Grid>
```

This works fine but I have two kinds of user GUEST  and customer 
 and they have different properties

**I want to bind the selected client CURRENT USER conditionality** 
 if user is GUEST to other my guest template and is user is customer
 type to my customer templet!

**I have the following Templetes**

```
         <!--  Customer templete  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="customerTemplete" DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">

        <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image Source="/EtimerServer;component/rec/user.png" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding StartSession}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding Elapsed}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding Balance}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />


        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>

    <!--  guest templete  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="guestTemplete" DataType="{x:Type local:Guest}">

        <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image Source="/EtimerServer;component/rec/user.png" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding StartSession}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding Elapsed}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

            <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       Text="{Binding TotalPayment}"
                       TextAlignment="Center" />


        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking - do you want to vary the template within the items of the list box? Or in the user details grid? Is it based on who is using the app or what item is selected in the list box?

Comment: in the users detail grid , based on who is using the app.

Comment: As a note, if there is a security issue with the wrong type of user seeing the wrong type of details, you should handle that in code-behind. Otherwise, with tools like Snoop WPF it is easy to change bindings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you should have a ContentControl binded to the CurrentUser property in the ViewModel. Then according to the type you place there the Correct Template will be selected.
your entities need to derive from the same base class:

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity
{

}

public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
}

public class Guest:BaseEntity
{
}
```

your view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BaseEntity _currentUser;
    public BaseEntity CurrentUser
    {
        get { return _currentUser; }
        set { _currentUser = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and your view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="customerTemplete" DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">

            <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Source="/EtimerServer;component/rec/user.png" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding StartSession}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding Elapsed}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding Balance}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />


            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        <!--  guest templete  -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="guestTemplete" DataType="{x:Type local:Guest}">

            <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Source="/EtimerServer;component/rec/user.png" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding StartSession}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding Elapsed}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />

                <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   Text="{Binding TotalPayment}"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />


            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentUser}"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```